# Conditional reduction in CUDA

Tags: performance, cuda, synchronization, sum

I need to sum about `100000` values stored in an array, but with conditions.

Is there a way to do that in CUDA to produce fast results?

Can anyone post a small code to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that, to perform conditional reduction, you can directly introduce the condition as a multiplication by `0` (false) or `1` (true) to the addends. In other words, suppose that the condition you would like to meet is that the addends be smaller than `10.f`. In this case, borrowing the first code at [Optimizing Parallel Reduction in CUDA by M. Harris](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf), then the above would mean

```
__global__ void reduce0(int *g_idata, int *g_odata) {

    extern __shared__ int sdata[];

    // each thread loads one element from global to shared mem
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    sdata[tid] = g_idata[i]*(g_data[i]<10.f);
    __syncthreads();

    // do reduction in shared mem
    for(unsigned int s=1; s < blockDim.x; s *= 2) {
        if (tid % (2*s) == 0) {
            sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    // write result for this block to global mem
    if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}
```

If you wish to use CUDA Thrust to perform conditional reduction, you can do the same by using `thrust::transform_reduce`. Alternatively, you can create a new vector `d_b` copying in that all the elements of `d_a` satisfying the predicate by `thrust::copy_if` and then applying `thrust::reduce` on `d_b`. I haven't checked which solution performs the best. Perhaps, the second solution will perform better on sparse arrays. Below is an example with an implementation of both the approaches.

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/count.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

// --- Operator for the first approach
struct conditional_operator { 
    __host__ __device__ float operator()(const float a) const {
    return a*(a<10.f);
    }
};

// --- Operator for the second approach
struct is_smaller_than_10 {
    __host__ __device__ bool operator()(const float a) const {
        return (a<10.f);
    }
};

void main(void) 
{
    int N = 20;

    // --- Host side allocation and vector initialization
    thrust::host_vector<float> h_a(N,1.f);
    h_a[0] = 20.f;
    h_a[1] = 20.f;

    // --- Device side allocation and vector initialization
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_a(h_a);

    // --- First approach
    float sum = thrust::transform_reduce(d_a.begin(), d_a.end(), conditional_operator(), 0.f, thrust::plus<float>());
    printf("Result = %f\n",sum);

    // --- Second approach
    int N_prime = thrust::count_if(d_a.begin(), d_a.end(), is_smaller_than_10());
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_b(N_prime);
    thrust::copy_if(d_a.begin(), d_a.begin() + N, d_b.begin(), is_smaller_than_10());
    sum = thrust::reduce(d_b.begin(), d_b.begin() + N_prime, 0.f);
    printf("Result = %f\n",sum);

    getchar();

}
```

Comment: I cant use vector in my program. So I tried the 1st method. It returns only zero. I found the same code in a NVIDIA presentation, didn't work

Comment: What does it mean that you cannot use vector in your code?

Comment: So there is no combined version, i.e. a "reduce if"?

Comment: @masterxilo No, there is not a direct `reduce_if`, see [Thrust reductions](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__reductions.html). However, you can see the two solutions indicated above as a way to implement it starting from other Thrust primitives.